# Is there a plugin/method to make Trillian reconnect immediately on connectivity loss?

Tags: networking, trillian

I work at a company that uses Trillian to manage all of our instant messaging. We have two internet connections. The primary connection is extremely unreliable. We have something set up that automatically fails over to the secondary when the primary "blinks", which takes about 50ms. However, our external IP then changed. If I'm using Trillian when such a "blink" happens, I have to manually click the "Reconnect" button.

Is there some way to have trillian automatically attempt a reconnect *as soon* as connectivity is lost?

Comment: Considering that this affects a lot more than just Trillian, perhaps you need to look at your network configuration.

Comment: I don't disagree, but small steps....